# NHibernate QueryOver RowCount, differentiate between 0 and NULL

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm trying to get all active tasks from an employee by `QueryOver` and `RowCount` with this code:

```
 var id = 1;
 var activeTasks = Session
    .QueryOver<Employee>()
    .Where(emp => emp.id == id)
    .JoinQueryOver<Tasks>(emp => emp.Tasks, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Where(task => task.State == TaskState.Active)
    .RowCount();
```

If there is no employee with the specified `id`, `RowCount()` returns `0`.
The thing is I need to know if the employee didn't exist or if there was no active tasks.

I could do this with 2 queries where I would first get the employee and check for null, then query for the tasks. But ideally if it's possible I would want this to go all in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it much simpler with LINQ to NHibernate:

```cs
var employeeWithActiveTaskCount = session
    .Query<Employee>()
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .GroupJoin(
        session
            .Query<Task>()
            .Where(t => t.State == TaskState.Active),
        e => e.Id,
        t => t.Employee.Id,
        (e, t) => new { Employee = e, Tasks = t })
    .Select(et => new 
        {
            EmployeeId = et.Employee.Id,
            TaskCount = et.Tasks.Count() 
        });
```

This will return only existing employees with appropriate number of tasks. In case the employee doesn't exist, empty collection is returned. The query generated by this looks as follows:

```sql
select employee0_.Id as col_0_0_, (select cast(count(*) as INT) 
    from [Task] task1_ where task1_.State=? 
    and (task1_.Employee_id=employee0_.Id
         or (task1_.Employee_id is null)
         and (employee0_.Id is null))) 
as col_1_0_ from [Employee] employee0_ where employee0_.Id=?
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this code and it works exacly how i want it to, i noticed however that this only works with the newer versions of NHibernate. The project i'm working on is using version 3.0.0.4000 and it throws an NotSupportedException.

Comment: @Alexander For older versions you probably need to go back from LINQ approach to `QueryOver` and use something like `SelectList` to return an array with two columns: id and row count.